# How can I get rid of having lists inside of a list in python?

Tags: python, list

```
    def digit_sum(n):
        n = str(n)
        empty = [x.split() for x in n]
        print empty



    digit_sum(21)
```

This code will output:

```
     [['2'], ['1']]
```

What I need is to make it:

```
    [2, 1]
```

so I can add the numbers in the list together. How do I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making a flat list out of list of lists in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python)

Comment: This is something like a duplicate of a duplicate of a duplicate... maybe a fourth- or fifth-order duplicate. Please search before asking.

Comment: Just remove the `.split()`, for one. What on earth is it doing there?

Answer (score 3):

I would just do (you don't need to `.split` it, just convert it to a string over which you can iterate):

```
def digit_sum(n):
    empty = [int(d) for d in str(n)]
    print empty
```

Demo:

```
>>> digit_sum(21)
[2, 1]
```

You could then obviously add them together with the `sum()` function.

Answer (score 2):

Don't call `split`. Split tries to divide a string on whitespace (by default). It will return a list of strings always (even if there were no splits to be made).

Since your loop is over a string, `x` will be a single character. That means you'll never have any whitespace to split on.

Just do `[x for x in n]` or `list(n)`.

Or if you want your digits as integers, rather than strings: `[int(x) for x in n]` or `map(int, n)`

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you

```
firstlist.append(secondlist)
```

Python should print 1, 2. Posting from a Windows Phone, so I can't run the code, excuse my incompetence if this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
def digit_sum(n):
  n = str(n)
  empty = [int(x) for x in n]
  print empty

digit_sum(21)
```

Output:

```
[2,1]
```

`split` returns a list. `for x in n` will go over each character in the string and `int(x)` converts the character to an integer.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> x = [['2'], ['1']]
>>> map(int, chain(*x))
[2, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to completely flatten a list of lists, you need to check if its iterable.

To do this you can create a generator which returns a non-iterable item, or recursively calls itself if the item is iterable.

Then place each element of the generator in a list, and print it.

## Warning!!

This will crash with cycling lists ie `l = []; l.append(l)`

```
def get_single_elements(item):
    if hasattr(item, '__iter__'):
        for child_item in item:
            for element in get_single_elements(child_item):
                yield element
    else:
        yield item

def print_flat(item):
    print [element for element in get_single_elements(item)]
    

>>> print_flat([[[0],[1]]])
[0, 1]
>>> print_flat([[[[[0,[1,2,[3,4]]]]],[[1]]]])
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1]
```

**Edit** if you're sure you want to convert all items to ints, then write it like this

```
def print_flat(item):
        print [int(element) for element in get_single_elements(item)]
```